# How to get value of a child integer in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
    users
       MOHSdOBElcSdMWp4GwBBSXUVyws2
         email: "abc@abc.com"
         outItems
             1234: "Dec 20, 2016 3:21:24 AM"
             2345: "Dec 20, 2016 2:08:58 AM"
         role: 1
         userName: "abc"
```

I have this Firebase Android database and I tried retrieve the value of role (i.e. 1).

I added a listener to the reference:

```
    mDatabase.child("users/userId/role").addValueEventListener(new addValueEventListener() {...});
```

Given that it is an integer/long value, how can I get the value with DataSnapShot? I tried to print off the value but it says {key is role, value is null}. Why is that?

Here is my implementation of the listener:

```
            mDatabase.child("users/userId/role").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    Long role = (Long) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                    if (role == 1) {
                        Intent n = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListItemsActivity.class);
                        startActivity(n);
                    } else
                        showAlertDialog();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: Could you provide your implementation for the listener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you, in any chance, forget to replace the `/userId/` with `MOHSdOBElcSdMWp4GwBBSXUVyws2` (as you mentioned) text in this line?

```
mDatabase.child("users/userId/role")
```